# Using keychain inside a launchd system daemon

Tags: macos, keychain, launchd

We have a launchd daemon that stores usernames and passwords from inside the keychain. It works when we try to add (with SecKeychainAddGenericPassword) remove (with SecKeychainFindGenericPassword and SecKeychainItemDelete) but we are unable to get the password we have set with SecKeychainFindGenericPassword. The function returns

```
-25293 errSecAuthFailed : The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.
```

The daemon signed and running as root. The password is saved inside the System keychain.

When we run the app from a terminal with sudo, it works. It is able to access the password. But when it's running inside launchd, it doesn't work. Is there anything preventing us from using the keychain inside launchd?

Thanks,
Marc-Etienne